# Beautifulsoup: get class name for each word

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a function that will tell me the class of the tag for each word in a text.

My html is something like this:

```
<p>
<span class="A">I am </span>
<span class="B"><span class="C"> not </span> doing a great job </span>
</p>
```

So I would like to create a function that returns a list:

```
[["I", A], ["am", A], ["not", C], ["doing", B], ["a", B], ["great", B], ["job", B]]
```

I have tried to loop all spans with FindAll('span', recursive=False) and by checking for each span if there are children, but I always get doubles.
For example, I would get "not doing a great job" and "not".

```
for p in p_tags:
  my_tag_list = []
  spans = p.findAll("span", recursive=False)
  for s in spans:
    text = s.text.split()
    for t in text:
       my_tag = []
       my_tag.append(t)
       my_tag.append(s["class"][0])
```

I have looked at the documentation, but I do not seem to find any method that will get me the text and the direct span around it.

Thank you in advance for any help,
Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the text nodes via the `find_all(text=True)`, go up the tree and get the class attribute of a [`.parent`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parent):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<p>
<span class="A">I am </span>
<span class="B"><span class="C"> not </span> doing a great job </span>
</p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

result = []
for text in soup.p.find_all(text=True):
    parent = text.parent
    parent_class = parent["class"][0] if "class" in parent.attrs else ""
    for word in text.split():
        result.append([word, parent_class])

print(result)
```

Prints:

```
[[u'I', u'A'], [u'am', u'A'], [u'not', u'C'], [u'doing', u'B'],
 [u'a', u'B'], [u'great', u'B'], [u'job', u'B']]
```